# Applying correct colours to elevation raster

Tags: qgis, raster, color

I have a problem to display elevation data with pseudocolours. The channel 1 is from -3.40282e+38 to 149.717 . A colleague used 1.7. and it looks like it should (from blue to Red)
when I use QGis 1.8 the complete raster is red with an unreasonable classified legend with four colours (three with minus values, one with maximum value red)

How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My first guess is that -3.40282e+38 is the Null value and that your colleague's system correctly recognized and handled that but it doesn't work on your system.

Try specifying the null value or just create a colormap that makes sense.